# Is there Predefined-Macros define about byte order in armcc

Tags: c, armcc, predefined-macro

Is there Predefined-Macros define about byte order in armcc.

I am a novice on the armcc.and sorry for my English.

In gcc these are macros:

`__BYTE_ORDER__
__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__
...`

Now I have to use armcc,
Is there same like these with armcc?

Thank a lot.

by the way,the armcc version:

```
ARM C/C++ Compiler, 4.1 [Build 713]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to this page: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_BABJFEFG.htm

You have `__BIG_ENDIAN` which is defined when compiling for a big endian target.

Comment: if  undef `__BIG_ENDIAN` means "little endian"?These are only two kinds of Byte Order.Is there maybe `__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__` ? I do not want to miss any possibility.

Comment: That's correct. If you need to target a [PDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) one day, you'll have to get a new compiler anyway!